# Is it possible to run a desktop application against a cloud-based SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, azure, remote-access

Currently our windows desktop applications run against a SQL Server instance that resides on our network. I'd like to remove the local instance and seamlessly assess the data from a remote SQL Server instance such as Azure.  I could write a middle tier, such as WCF, but I'd rather not.  It would be easiest just gain direct access to the SQL server.  Can this be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336282.aspx

You'll need to ensure that the Azure SQL Database firewall rules are set up to allow traffic from your IP.

If you are running full SQL Server on a Windows Azure Virtual Machine you can open the port to the SQL Server.  Be aware that you'd likely want to ACL the endpoints on a VM to restrict access to your IPs.

Comment: Two more things I would like to mention is that since the database won't be local so there would be some slowness in the response from database (because of Internet latency) and also prepare your application to handle transient errors.

Answer (score 0):

Remote SQL Server and Azure could be very different things.

First difference that you will found is the Connection String form. Azure SQL connection strings looks like:
Server=tcp:xxxxxxxx.database.windows.net;Database=xxxxxxxx;User ID=xxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxxxx;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;